# Copy array to hash

Tags: perl

I'm trying to copy an array to a hash, such that each element of the array is a key, followed by an empty value.

```
my %questions = map { @u_list => $_ } @u_list;
```

This only prints out

```
=>
```

I see on perldoc this idiom:

```
     %hash = map { get_a_key_for($_) => $_ } @array;
```

But I cannot figure out how to set the keys. I want the keys to be each element in the array.

Comment: `my %questions = map { $_ => undef } @u_list;` Or, instead of undef, "" or 0.

Comment: Can I write %questions = map { "$_\t" => '' } @u_list; To add a tab after the key?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
my %questions = map { $_ => undef } @u_list;
```

In the map, each element of `@u_list` gets set to $_.

Answer (score 10):

Super confusing but functional answer:

```
@questions{@u_list}=();
```

This is using the hash slice syntax to specify a set of hash keys..

Comment: slice syntax, eh? It looks very dense. I'll have to look into that.

Comment: It can also be used to set every element to the same value: `@questions{@u_list}=("unknown")x@u_list` to set every question to the string "unknown".

Answer (score 3):

```
 %hash = map { $_ => '' } @array;
```

This sets the values to an empty string

Answer (score 2):

`$_` is the current element of your list `@u_list`.

So you have to say

`my %questions = map {  $_ => 1 } @u_list;`

to map your list elements as hash keys.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few different ways to do this, just for reference.

Using `map`

```
my %questions = map { $_, undef } @u_list;
```

Using a `foreach`

```
my %questions;
$questions{$_} = undef foreach ( @u_list );
```

Using a `hash slice`.

```
my %questions;
@questions{@u_list} = (undef) x @u_list;
```